# triggering change of radio button by using on click trigger using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hav a 5 radios and when it loads it runs

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].trigger('change');
```

to activate the below function

```
(function() {
$("form#form1 input, form#form1 select").on('keyup change', function() {
alert('called')
}):
}).call(this);
```

But trigger('change') will not neither trigger('click')

Comment: Needs to be a JQuery solution?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].trigger('change');
```

try

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].click();
```

It will make the checkbox checked if it is unchecked, or vice versa. You can also use:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].attr('checked', true);
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].attr('checked', false);
```

or

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].prop('checked', true);
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: No i am not, this $("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].attr('checked', true);
$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].attr('checked', false); is not a function

Comment: I did not get you?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[1].prop is not a function

Comment: $("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].click();
will click the radio but does not fire

Comment: Try this one: `$("input[type='radio'][name='freq']")[1].click().change();`

Comment: VM128 userCodeAppPanel:224 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", functio_test);
document.getElementById("myBtn1").addEventListener("click", functio_test);

        function functio_test(){
            var x = document.querySelector('input[name="type_test"]:checked').value;
            if(x == "ola"){
                 alert("Ola José");
            }
            else if(x == "adeus"){
                 alert("Adeus José");
            }
            else {
                alert("Continua José");
            }
        }
```

```html
<input id = "myBtn" type="radio" name="type_test" value="ola"> ola <br/>
    <input id = "myBtn1" type="radio" name="type_test" value="adeus"> adeus <br/>
```